# PayPal error: 'Your session has timed out, please log in again'

Tags: php, paypal

During testing my online store's payment gateway with PayPal sandbox the following error

> '*Your session has timed out, please log in again.*'

over and over again. It is occurring right at the very end of the payment process when PayPal tries to pass the user back to the online store.

I have already deleted all my browser-cookies and tested it with different browsers.

Yesterday my PayPal ipn script worked just fine and without any issues and I haven't edited it. So I guess this isn't causing the error.

Does anyone may have any idea what may could cause this problem?

Comment: how many request did you send ? maybe they block your IP address.

Comment: I have probably send something about 35-40 requests that day and another 20-25 the days before. I will try it via my mobile phone and a secont internet router again.

Comment: I have now tried to make a sandbox payment using my cellphone and there the follwomg error occurred at the same place : 'paypal dispatch error please check logfile for more information'

Comment: maybe you can show some of your code.